# Magento : Get invoice id from invoice incrementId

Tags: php, magento

I'm creating a magento extension in which I desire to get the invoice id from the invoice incrementId

I want the invoice id as 1,2,3.... from increment id which is like 100000001,100000002,100000003 ..........

Here is the code which i used to generate invoice.

```
$invoiceId = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice_api')
    ->create($order->getIncrementId(), array(), 'Invoice Created', true, true);
```

It gives me invoiceId as 100000001,100000002,100000003.

Comment: Do you want the "real" invoice entity id, or do you want to use the returned increment_id, but just without the leading 100000000?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$incrementId = '100000001';

$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

$invoiceId = $invoice->getId();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `create` method will return `$invoice->getIncrementId();`

See /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice/Api.php

To get invoice id you could load the invoice by increment id

```
$invoiceIncrementId = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice_api')->create($order->getIncrementId(), array(), 'Invoice Created', true, true);

$invoiceId = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->loadByIncrementId($invoiceIncrementId)->getId();
```